# FSCTL_SET_REPAIR IOCTL values?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, ntfs

I'm confused, the docs for the IOCTL don't say anything.

The docs for fsutil say:

```
- 0x01: Enables general repair.
- 0x09: Warns about potential data loss without repair.
- 0x00: Disables NTFS self-healing repair operations.
```

The fsutil program itself says:

```
Values: 0x1 - Enable general repair.
        0x9 - Enable repair and warn about potential data loss.
        0x10 - Disable repair and bugcheck once on first corruption.
```

So which one is correct?  Does 9 do repair and issue message or does it not do a repair an only issue a message?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa964904?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) page.

It is apparent that being warned of errors requires that self-healing be turned on to begin with. Keep in mind that 9 is 8|1.

Comment: Finally a page that actually shows something.  The only page I could find using search engines was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_set_repair which is worthless.   While your doc link matches the program itself, it still conflicts with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-repair